# Haskell parse list of integers with Attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I need some help parsing a list of comma delimited integers from a file, when the list of integers can be any length. The string might look like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,..." and the list I need made would be like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...].

The file format looks like:

```
0,0:1; -- minimum of 1 integer after the :
0,1:1,2;
0,2:5;
0,3:5,16,223,281; -- any amount of integers can follow the :
...
```

My parser currently only reads one integer, but it needs to start reading more. I can use takeTill to read all the numbers into a ByteString, but then I have to parse yet another string with the same problem of not knowing exactly how many numbers there can be:

```
parseTile :: Parser Tile
parseTile = do
  x <- decimal
  char ','
  y <- decimal
  char ':'
  --t <- takeTill (\x -> x == ';')
  t <- decimal
  char ';'
  return $ Tile x y t
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898602/haskell-how-to-use-attoparsec-in-order-to-read-a-nested-list-from-a-bytestring), but it doesn't help me because my file isn't a json file.

Comment: You should look at the `sepBy*` combinators, you can get something like ```commaSepInts = decimal `sepBy1` (char ',')```; ```row = commaSepInts `sepBy1` (char ':')```.  Not sure if this solves all your problems, but `sepBy` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks bheklilr, sepBy was indeed the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sepBy` and `decimal`:

```
parseTile :: Parser Tile
parseTile = do
  x <- decimal
  char ','
  y <- decimal
  char ':'
  t <- decimal `sepBy` (char ',')
  char ';'
  return $ Tile x y t
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew there had to be an easy answer, but I couldn't put my finger on it.